# vb.net Is there a limit to the number of objects you can create?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to find the limit, if there is one, of the number of objects you can create.

Logically there is a limit and this limit would be that of the capacity of the RAM but to test concretely I established this piece of code and I let it run

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim newObj As New classTest.classTest
        Dim i As Int64
        Dim MAX As Int64
        MAX = 9223372036854775807 ' max 64 bits int
        For i = 1 To MAX
            newObj = New classTest.classTest
            Console.WriteLine(i)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

I let this code run for a while and it didn't crash, so I thought of a possible limitation like :

- RAM Amount
- OS Architecture (32/64bits)
- Memory Swap on/off

But these are just guesses, my teacher wants the limit and proof of it, can someone help me or direct me please?

Comment: You are creating objects but you store only one, so the GC can collect your garbage, meaning ram should not be the limit

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, it's true that I don't store the objects that are created because I haven't figured out how to store them and create them in a loop, but that's what I'm trying to do to find the limit.

Comment: add them to a `List(Of classTest.classTest)`

Comment: The limit isn't RAM but rather the size of your swap file, subject to your disk space and the virtual memory limit of your CPU and Windows version (for Win10 64bit CPU and process it's 128TB)

Comment: @RBarryYoung How did you come up with 128TB for this configuration?

Comment: @ccalex See here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-10/anyone-single-64-bit-process-only-can-be-allocated-4gb-memory-in/m-p/1565518.  But presumably you'll run out of pagefile/disk space well before then.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Ok, thanks, that's very helpful, but if memory swap is disabled, what would be the limit?

Comment: @ccalex In that case, it's how much RAM your process can get, which is limited by 1) how much RAM your PC has, 2) how much the OS uses, 3) how much other processes are holding onto, and 4) the working set limit of your process.  Basically, you cannot get more RAM than exists on your PC, but you may not be able/allowed to get all of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping all the objects you create.  Replace your code with this

```
    Dim newObj As classTest.classTest
    Dim newObjCollection As New List(Of classTest.classTest)
    Dim i As Int64
    Dim MAX As Int64 = Int64.MaxValue
    For i = 1L To MAX
        newObj = New classTest.classTest
        newObjCollection.Add(newObj)
        Console.WriteLine(i)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
```

I suspect you'll crash with out of memory.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to put it in a try-catch, so you know on what number it crashed.

Comment: Note that the List class itself has an upper limit (2 billion elements) that is much lower than the theoretical number of objects creatable (which is limited to 128TB memory for 64bit Win10, so maybe 8 billion objects?).

Comment: @RBarryYoung - do you have a reference for the theoretical limit?

Comment: @dbasnett The 128TB limit is noted here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-10/anyone-single-64-bit-process-only-can-be-allocated-4gb-memory-in/m-p/1565518, I'm not sure where it might be in the doc.

Comment: @dbasnett Found the doc reference, 5th bullet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/virtual-address-spaces

Comment: @TimSchmelter I added a try-catch but how do I print out or get the value of the "i" variable so I know on what number it crashed ?

Comment: You should have tagged @ccalex dbasnett.

Comment: @ccalex if the try catch is around the for loop you shouldn't have issue with getting i.